# Accesing openlayers.map in index.html

Tags: openlayers-2, html

I am developing an app using [OpenTripPlanner](http://www.opentripplanner.org/).

It creates an OpenLayers map in `map.js`.

How do I access this map in `index.html` so I can set it's center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think OpenTripPlanner uses OpenLayers so I have checked it and it uses Leaflet so you have to use following method for centering your map.  You can put it anywhere after your map.js is loaded.

> _container    div#map2.leaflet-container

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lon, lat));
```

Answer (score 1):

In index.html :

```
<head>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

In myscript.js

```
mapVariable.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat( yourLon, yourLat) , theZoomLevel );
```